# pdo::execute($array) not going in table no errors

Tags: php, pdo, execute

i am using this code currently and there are no errors it it just not adding it too the table.

```
$fields["firstName"] = $_POST['firstName']; 
$fields["middleName"] = $_POST['middleName'];
$fields["lastName"] = $_POST['lastName']; 
$fields["suffix"] = $_POST['suffix'];
$fields["age"] = $_POST['age'];
.....etc


$t = array();
foreach($fields as $k=>$v)
{
$count++;
$n .= $k;
$u .= $k;
if($count != count($fields))
{
    $n .= ", ";
    $u .= ", :";
}
$s = ":".$k;
$t[$s]= $v;
}

 $q="INSERT INTO search_requests SET (".$n.") VALUE(:".$u.")";

 $prep=$conn->prepare($q);
 $prep->execute($t);
```

can you use an array like that or do i have have to write out each variable in the execute function

```
 $prep->execute(array(':firstName=>$_POST['firstName'], etc..));
```

the sql code

```
INSERT INTO search_requests SET (user_email, datestamp, historicalMatches, 
firstName, middleName, lastName, suffix, etc...) VALUE(:user_email, 
:datestamp, :historicalMatches, :firstName, :middleName, :lastName, :suffix,etc...)
```

they all match.

```
Array ( [:user_email] => Email@domain.com [:datestamp] => 02 Nov 2012 10.24.39 AM   
[:historicalMatches] => [:firstName] => First [:middleName] => m [:lastName] => lastname 
[:suffix] => etc...)
```

Comment: why not just try it out?

Comment: You can do it the way you suggest. Just get the quotes in the right place...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I would recommend that you do a print $q; to see if the code produces the correct sql.